# Unable to open the camera through Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm new to Cordova and trying to develop on app for android in which I need to open the Camera. But I'm unable to do. Below is the approach I followed:

```
var app = {
   initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    document.getElementById('camera').addEventListener('click',function(e){
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail,{
            quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL});})
    },
function onSuccess(imageData){
    var image=document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src="data:img/jpeg;base64,"+imageData;
}
function onFail(message){
    alert('Failed because: '+message);
}
receivedEvent: function(id) {
        console.log(id)
}
};
app.initialize();
```

After building and opening with Android emulator Camera is not getting opened. Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
app.js
```

```js
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {
 
    $scope.takePicture = function() {
        var options = { 
            quality : 75, 
            destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, 
            sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
            allowEdit : true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 300,
            targetHeight: 300,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };
 
        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }, function(err) {
            // An error occured. Show a message to the user
        });
    }
 
});
```

```html
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
 
 <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 
        
    </head>
    <body ng-app="starter">
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}">
  <img ng-show="imgURI === undefined" ng-src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  <button class="button" ng-click="takePicture()">Take Picture</button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```